# Is it safe to use the prompt() function from a Chrome Extension to ask for a password?

Tags: javascript, security, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a small extension, and to ease my job, I'd like to use

```
prompt("enter password");
```

so that the user can enter his/her password. I know the prompt will show the password as plain text but what are some other security problems? Can other websites have access to the content of this prompt(which would be a huge deal in this case)?

Comment: I don't think you can even get `prompt` on an extension?

Comment: @MinusFour: I think he's talking about [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/content_scripts/).

Comment: Beyond [shoulder surfing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoulder_surfing_%28computer_security%29), I don't think it should be different from any other form or input field--the password winds up in a variable (or state in the DOM, in the case of forms). Browser code is never secure. Other sites can have access to it through any other means of stealing user input--key loggers, XSS, etc.

Comment: Well, for one thing, they can do this: `var THE_PASSWORD; prompt = function( s ){ THE_PASSWORD = prompt(s); broadcastToEvilSite(THE_PASSWORD); return "A fake password or maybe the real password if you want"; };`

Comment: @LakshyaRaj Content scripts can't access variables created by the web page. So when it calls `prompt()` it will get the standard function, not something the web page defined.

Comment: Well, as a content-script I guess it could work. So long as it make sense to use a page execution context.

Comment: You can encrypt the password in a non-reversible way, and then re-encrypt any input passwords and check if it matches the encrypted password. Maybe use some SHA encryption or something else? Helpful link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aren't worried about the entered text being displayed without `***`s, then it looks fine. It'll be as safe as pretty much any other JS handling of passwords.

> Can other websites have access to the content of this prompt

If it's a content script, they could, if they intercepted the `window.prompt` and overwrote it with their own implementation, eg:

```js
// page script:
const originalPrompt = window.prompt;
window.prompt = (text) => {
  const result = originalPrompt(text);
  // HERE, the page can do something malicious with the result
  // such as sending it to their server
  console.log('Page detected:', result);
  return result;
};


// Your script:

prompt('Password?');
```

But this approach would compromise pretty much *any* handling of passwords on the front-end - it's not an issue with the `prompt`, but with the front-end in general.

To get around this problem in a content script, make sure that the `prompt` that you call is the *native* code version, which can only be done in a foolproof way by running your code before any other code on the page runs. Save a reference to the original prompt on `document_start`.

Also, make sure to do the validation on the *backend*, not the frontend. If your JS is like

```
const userInput = prompt("enter password");
if (userInput !== 'theTruePassword') {
  // wrong
  return;
}
// do stuff
```

then it would be trivial for anyone with access to the website to bypass the password check and get to the `do stuff` by examining the source code. Instead, make sure to send the password to a *server* and have the server validate whether it's correct, *then* have the server send the sensitive information back to the client.

Comment: As [Barmar said to me](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66500409#comment117561653_66500409), content scripts will get the real functions, but good explanation otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I wont recommend using prompt so here's a little code that you can modify to show your contents after the correct password has been set

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <label>enter your pin :</label>
            <input type="text" id="pin" name="pin"><br>
    <br>
            <button id="mybutton" onclick="myfunction()">enter</button>
            <p id="demo"></p>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              function myfunction() 
              {
                if ((document.getElementById("pin").value)=="4567") 
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "you have the correct password"
                else
                    alert("incorrect password")
               }
            </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

You can also change the passcode that I has set to anything you want

Comment: Something cool you might not know is that you can have an `input` with a `type` of `password`, then anything you type will appear as dots. Also, checking if the password is correct should not be done in a script tag, but on the backend with node.js or similar.